# Will grafting seed grown citrus onto a rootstock bring fruiting forward

Tags: citrus, grafting

So Iv got a nice variety of mandarin from the supermarket and am growing it from seed. Iv heard fruiting can take yeeeeears of grown this way. Iv seen a fruiting bitter orange for sale online for £25, if I buy this and graft on the mandarin once it's big enough to graft will this mean the mandarin should fruit within a couple of years once the graft is established ?.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Taking a bud or a graft from the mandarin seedling will result in a clone of the motherplant, therefore it will have the same genetic maturity and won't fruit earlier. For having your own mandarin fruits as soon as possible, take a bud or a graft from an already fruiting mandarin tree, thus making a clone of it, and graft it on existing rootstock.

Obsolete answer: Yes, the graft will produce fruit in a few years, but it will produce bitter orange, not mandarin fruits.

Comment: I thought the idea of grafting another variety on was to get that fruit ?. Iv got a peach and nectarine tree, half grows peach, the other grafted half grows nectarine. Are you saying the mandarins graft won't do this and grow the rootstock fruit instead ?.

Comment: Sorry, from your question I understood that you grow a mandarin from seed and planning on grafting a bitter orange on the mandarin rootstock. Was it the other way around?

Comment: No I was going to buy a bitter orange (already fruiting), and graft a seed grown mandarin onto the bitter orange, so the rootstock would be bitter orange and the sion would be the year old mandarin growth from seed.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Alina What's your source for your information?